# Rests Silently Dead in Salt!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Here's a quick fun riddle -

> It wasn't indeed, but was in dead.
>   A snake bites at back, takes it to a Chinese County.
>   Ahead of time, it enhanced into a color.
>   Back it up, and it became a Legend.
>   I look after it and it goes on a Voyage.

**What was that?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It wasn't indeed, but was in dead.

> The letter "a". Not in DEED but in De'A'd

A snake bites at back, takes it to a Chinese County.

> Apparently, there is a Chinese county named [AN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anzhou_District) As for N as Snake, just see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N). the Egyptian heiroglyph makes it quite clear.

Ahead of time, it enhanced into a color.

> Time=t(As in Physics). TAN is a color.

Back it up, and it became a Legend.

> Add TI(Reversed IT) to the front(So that the intial word remains at the back) (Observed by tmpearce) and (As M Oehm says),we get [TITAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(mythology))

I look after it and it goes on a Voyage.

> Oehm astutely observes here that I look= I see=IC. Adding that to the end, we get TITANIC which got wrecked on its first voyage.(I suppose, I don't have to provide any links for this? ;) )

Now for the title,

> TITANIC is wrecked and is right now, silently in the Ocean.(Salt=Sea-water)

And thus, our hardwork comes to an end with the final answer of:

> TITANIC.

Comment: Nice start. :) Now, this is close.

Comment: Hmm, @TEch How close? 50%?

Comment: Yes. ^ More or less.

Comment: Dang it I had this! ;_;

Comment: I think the legend is a TITAN and IC ("I look/see") after it gives TITANIC, which went on a single voyage. (But doesn't "ahead of time" mean that the T comes after AN?)

Comment: @MOehm I assumed "ahead of time" to mean that whatever I had initially, to come ahead of time(in this case, "t")

Comment: I agree with @MOehm on TITAN/IC, and I took the 3rd one as a *head* of time = T

Comment: I think it is ahead of the word "TIME", which is the first letter in TIME = T

Comment: I think - a head of time means add T to the head (ie front); back it up could mean "it" in reverse ("ti") to the front, giving TITAN; "I see" to the end ->TITANIC

Comment: Also - TITANIC fits with the title; shipwrecked in the ocean = salt water

Answer (score 1):

Here is my totally random guess...

Is it a

> Dragon?

It wasn't indeed, but was in dead.

> It wasn't living in this world (not indeed) but out of it ("dead" / world of the afterlife)

A snake bites at back, takes it to a Chinese County.

> Dragons are huge in Chinese culture. Maybe originating from snakes

Ahead of time, it enhanced into a color.

> Not sure. Different color dragons, or the colorful cultures revolving around them

Back it up, and it became a Legend.

> Many legends include dragons

I look after it and it goes on a Voyage.

> Viking ships were equipped with dragons in the front.

Comment: If there was no wordplay tag, this would have been a good answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

## Partial

Is it

> The letter `d`?

It wasn't indeed, but was in dead.

> The letter `d` is in the word `dead`

A snake bites at back, takes it to a Chinese County.

> Not sure

Ahead of time, it enhanced into a color.

> Not sure. May have something to do with the color 'red'

Back it up, and it became a Legend.

> May refer to the [Legend of Wheezin' Ed](http://heyarnold.wikia.com/wiki/Legend_of_Wheezin%27_Ed)

I look after it and it goes on a Voyage.

> Not sure

Comment: Nope. Nowhere close. Sorry.

Comment: @Techidiot If that's no where close I assume the letter 'a' would also be the wrong direction too? (Was thinking no in deed but in dead)

Comment: @n_palum I said, this answer. Like most of it is either not sure or way too stretched.